# Import CSV to Excel and transform data

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file that contains logged integers and reals, like this:

```
LocalDate,LocalTime,{[Bay1]Bay1_DINT[0]},{[Bay1]Bay1_DINT[1]},{[Bay1]Bay1_DINT[2]},etc,etc,
10/15/2014,16:06:40,32904,32896,49288,0,0,31744,0,6,0,0,8064,0,0,35,0,0,0,0,1.34,5,6.79,4.97,0.77,999,999,0,0,0,0,0,1175.17,1177.47,1179,1180,1151,1149,600,0.78,2.94,4.02,2.93,0.45,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am trying to use powershell to import the csv into excel, transform the ints into binary, and split each bit into separate (new)columns, and leave the reals alone.

I'm just starting the uphill curve of learning powershell, so I know enough to import the csv into excel and that's about it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could add data to the CSV in PowerShell what you would need is a `ForEach` loop to step through all "rows" and you could use the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add the "columns" that you want which would leave the current data alone. Once you start with that if you are still stuck update your question. As it stands this question might get closed since your not explicit with what code you have and what the end result is supposed to be like. Reduce your sample data to only what you need to get the job done and you can then extrapolate that with your real data.

Comment: Hey that's a great suggestion. Thanks Matt.